# Search unsorted array for 3 elements which sum to a value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, time-complexity

I am trying to make an algorithm, of Θ( n² ).
It accepts an unsorted array of **n** elements, and an integer **z**,
and has to return 3 indices of 3 **different** elements a,b,c ; so a+b+c = z.
 (return NILL if no such integers were found)

I tried to sort the array first, in two ways, and then to search the sorted array.
but since I need a specific running time for the rest of the algorithm, I am getting lost.
  Is there any way to do it without sorting? (I guess it does have to be sorted) either with or without sorting would be good.

**example**:
for this array :         `1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 9`  and the integer `6`

It has to return:  `0, 1, 3`

because ( 1+3+2 = 6)

Comment: O(n^2*logn) jumps to mind. Are you looking for O(n^2) algorithm? Or better?

Comment: Since Theta is more accurate, I need better  than O(n^2).  But actually I don't even find one of O(n^2).

Comment: What about memory constraints?

Comment: @norok2   No memory constraints.

Comment: @norok2    Where did you take your answer? I think it was the best..

Comment: @J.Y.P. I deleted it because it was wrong. That is worst case `O(n³)` because the first loop of the third block can actually contain up to `n²` items.

Comment: Can numbers be negative?

Comment: @norok2 Since it's not explicitly stated, I guess so. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm

1. Sort - O(nlogn)
2. for i=0... n-1 - O(1) assigning value to i
3. new_z = z-array[i] this value is updated each iteration. Now, search for new_z using two pointers, at begin (index 0) and end (index n-1) If sum (array[ptr_begin] + array[ptr_ens]) is greater then new_z, subtract 1 from the pointer at top. If smaller, add 1 to begin pointer. Otherwise return i, current positions of end and begin. - O(n)
4. jump to step 2 - O(1)

Steps 2, 3 and 4 cost O(n^2). Overall, O(n^2)

C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {3, 1, 4, 2, 9, 7, 6};
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    int z = 6;
    int no_success = 1;
    //std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto const &it) { std::cout << it << std::endl;});

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() && no_success; i++)
    {

        int begin_ptr = 0;
        int end_ptr = vec.size()-1;
        int new_z = z-vec[i];

        while (end_ptr > begin_ptr)
        {
            if(begin_ptr == i)
                begin_ptr++;
            if (end_ptr == i) 
                end_ptr--;

            if ((vec[begin_ptr] + vec[end_ptr]) > new_z)
                end_ptr--;
            else if ((vec[begin_ptr] + vec[end_ptr]) < new_z)
                begin_ptr++;
            else {
                std::cout << "indices are: " << end_ptr << ", " << begin_ptr << ", " << i << std::endl;
                no_success = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Beware, result is the sorted indices. You can maintain the original array, and then search for the values corresponding to the sorted array. (3 times O(n))

Comment: thanks but I need it to be Θ( n² ) which is kind of the average of the upper and lower notations.  To be exact: t(n) = Θ(g(n))  if and only if  t(n) = Ω(g(n)) and t(n) = O(g(n)) (look here for explanation about Θ)  https://www.programiz.com/dsa/asymptotic-notations

Comment: @TonyTannous, I really wonder how the overall time complexity of the given problem can be O(nlogn)? The solution you mentioned works for sum of two elements. However, author mentioned he is looking for the solution for sum of 3 elements summing upto a value.

Comment: This is not clear. What is step 2? Subtraction of all array elements from original z? Doesn't make sense. What is pointer at top in step 3?

Comment: @vivek_23 cpp solution will be attached shortly.

Comment: @vivek_23 not the most beautiful code. But should do.

Comment: @TonyTannous For loop runs n times in worst case and inner while loop can also visit all indices in worst case(say no match found), so it is O(n^2).

Comment: @vivek_23 the algorithm i suggest and did in code is O(n^2) indeed... :) but, if you do binary search with the pointers and not add or subtract 1, it will be O(nlong) (though when I think about it, i don't think it can be done?)

Comment: @TonyTannous Binary search doesn't help because we have 2 unknowns here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```py
def find_3sum_restr(items, z):
    # : find possible items to consider -- O(n)
    candidates = []
    min_item = items[0]
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        if item < z:
            candidates.append(i)
        if item < min_item:
            min_item = item
    # : find possible couples to consider -- O(n²)
    candidates2 = []
    for k, i in enumerate(candidates):
        for j in candidates[k:]:
            if items[i] + items[j] <= z - min_item:
                candidates2.append([i, j])
    # : find the matching items -- O(n³)
    for i, j in candidates2:
        for k in candidates:
            if items[i] + items[j] + items[k] == z:
                return i, j, k
```

This `O(n + n² + n³)`, hence `O(n³)`.

While this is reasonably fast for randomly distributed inputs (perhaps `O(n²)`?), unfortunately, in the worst case (e.g. for an array of all ones, with a `z > 3`), this is no better than the naive approach:

```
def find_3sum_naive(items, z):
    n = len(items)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            for k in range(j, n):
                if items[i] + items[j] + items[k] == z:
                    return i, j, k
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the `3 elements which sum to a value (say v)` can be done in O(n^2), where `n` is the length of the array, as follows:

1. Sort the given array. [ O(nlogn) ]
2. Fix the first element , say `e1`. (iterating from `i = 0` to `n - 1`)
3. Now we have to find the sum of 2 elements sum to a value `(v - e1)` in range from `i + 1` to `n - 1`. We can solve this sub-problem in `O(n)` time complexity using two pointers where left pointer will be pointing at `i + 1` and right pointer will be pointing at `n - 1` at the beginning. Now we will move our pointers either from left or right depending upon the total current sum is greater than or less than required sum.

So, overall time complexity of the solution will be `O(n ^ 2)`.

**Update:**

I attached solution in `c++` for the reference: (also, added comments to explain time complexity).

```
 vector<int> sumOfthreeElements(vector<int>& ar, int v) {
        sort(ar.begin(), ar.end());
        int n = ar.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < n - 2 ; ++i){ //outer loop runs `n` times
            //for every outer loop inner loops runs upto `n` times
            //therefore, overall time complexity is O(n^2).
            int lo = i + 1;
            int hi = n - 1;
            int required_sum = v - ar[i];
            while(lo < hi) {
                int current_sum = ar[lo] + ar[hi];
                if(current_sum == required_sum) {
                    return {i, lo, hi};
                } else if(current_sum > required_sum){
                     hi--;
                }else lo++;
            }
        }
        return {};
    }
```

Comment: nice but not Θ( n² )   :(

Comment: @J.Y.P, Looking at your first sentence I thought you are looking at O(n^2) solution. I will be really glad to see if there exists better approach than O(n^2).

Comment: Actually after I've thought of it, it is the complexity I was looking for- Θ( n² ). Thank you! (I hate this Theta thing..)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is similar to LeetCode 15 and 16:

### [LeetCode 16](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum-closest/)

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def threeSumClosest(self, nums, target):
        nums.sort()
        closest = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]
        for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
            j = -~i
            k = len(nums) - 1
            while j < k:
                summation = nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k]
                if summation == target:
                    return summation
                if abs(summation - target) < abs(closest - target):
                    closest = summation
                if summation < target:
                    j += 1
                elif summation > target:
                    k -= 1
        return closest
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public int threeSumClosest(int[] nums, int target) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        int closest = nums[0] + nums[nums.length >> 1] + nums[nums.length - 1];

        for (int first = 0; first < nums.length - 2; first++) {
            int second = -~first;
            int third = nums.length - 1;

            while (second < third) {
                int sum = nums[first] + nums[second] + nums[third];

                if (sum > target)
                    third--;

                else
                    second++;

                if (Math.abs(sum - target) < Math.abs(closest - target))
                    closest = sum;
            }
        }

        return closest;
    }
}
```

### [LeetCode 15](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/)

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        res = []
        nums.sort()
        for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
                continue
            lo, hi = -~i, len(nums) - 1
            while lo < hi:
                tsum = nums[i] + nums[lo] + nums[hi]
                if tsum < 0:
                    lo += 1
                if tsum > 0:
                    hi -= 1
                if tsum == 0:
                    res.append((nums[i], nums[lo], nums[hi]))
                    while lo < hi and nums[lo] == nums[-~lo]:
                        lo += 1
                    while lo < hi and nums[hi] == nums[hi - 1]:
                        hi -= 1
                    lo += 1
                    hi -= 1
        return res
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || (i > 0 && nums[i] != nums[i - 1])) {
                int lo = -~i, hi = nums.length - 1, sum = 0 - nums[i];
                while (lo < hi) {
                    if (nums[lo] + nums[hi] == sum) {
                        res.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[lo], nums[hi]));
                        while (lo < hi && nums[lo] == nums[-~lo])
                            lo++;
                        while (lo < hi && nums[hi] == nums[hi - 1])
                            hi--;
                        lo++;
                        hi--;
                    } else if (nums[lo] + nums[hi] < sum) {
                        lo++;
                    } else {
                        hi--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

#### Reference

You can see the explanations in the following links:

[LeetCode 15 - Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)

[LeetCode 16 - Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum-closest/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)

[LeetCode 15 - Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum-closest/solution/)